# ERROR SSPG.MainWindow - Couldn't clear IsolatedStorage on startup

Tags: support

As part of a Sitecore Support Ticket I was asked to use the Sitecore Support Pack Generator to provide informations about my site; I had installed and used it before changing OS to Windows 10, but now every attempt of running it returned the following error on the log:

```
ERROR SSPG.MainWindow - Couldn't clear IsolatedStorage on startup.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '<filename>' is denied.
```

Every attempt of fixing the problem by modifying permissions of the named file in my project or running SSPG as administrator failed. How can I address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I found on [this blog post](http://techitpro.com/uncategorized/sitecore-support-package-generator/#comment-48920) that I need to delete the files present under `C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Roaming\Sitecore\SSPG\Files\`, and this solved my problem.